# How to auto remove applied filters upon opening a file WITHOUT removing filter capabilities

Tags: excel, vba

I have a team that works remotely on a shared spreadsheet.  They can apply filters for search purposes.  I would like the spreadsheet to be able to have the filters previously applied cleared automatically upon closing OR opening the spreadsheet without deleting the ability to set future filters.  I cannot figure out the code to make this work.

I've searched these threads and tried many codes.  Some have come close and have removed the filters when opening the spreadsheet, but it also removes the ABILITY to filter.  This means that I have to turn on filtering each time I re-open the spreadsheet and that is not ideal. Code used is:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            If ws.AutoFilterMode Then
                ws.AutoFilterMode = False
            End If
        Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This will clear, but keep the filter:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.AutoFilterMode Then 
            ws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If 
    Next ws 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be the following:

```
Sub clearFilter()
Dim sht As Worksheet 'Declare a worksheet variable
Dim rng As Range 'Declare a Range variable
Dim j As Long
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of your Worksheet") 'The worksheet where the data is
Set rng = sht.Range("A:E") 'The range that is being filtered. In this case columns A,B,C,D,E are being filtered.

For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count Step 1 'loop through all the columns that are being filtered...
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=j '...and clear the filter while maintaining the filtering capabilities
Next j

End Sub
```